# Cannot Change TEdit Height in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Below is the sample code of my Custom TEdit control.

```
type
  TEdit = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit)
  private   
    //FTextM : TEXTMETRIC;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
  end;

constructor TEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin

  inherited Create(AOwner);
  BorderStyle := bsNone;
  Text := '';

  Font.Name := 'Segoe UI';
  Font.Size := 9;


  Height := 10;  //Here height change is not reflected.    
end;
```

Here what ever the value i give in **Height** it is not updated in runtime. I am seriously missing very simple thing. But i am unable to figure it out on my own.

What will be the correct way to update the height of tedit control.

Update: Here is the form code i am using.

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 242
  ClientWidth = 472
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Edit2: TEdit
    Left = 216
    Top = 184
    Width = 121
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'Edit2'
  end
  object Edit3: TEdit
    Left = 40
    Top = 136
    Width = 121
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 0
    Text = 'Edit3'
  end
end
```

Comment: You are probably putting the edit at design time, constructor is early to set any designable property - the component will stream and override the values you set.

Comment: yes i am putting tedit in design time. Any workarounds so the value i set is applied to the tedit component.

Comment: The proper thing to do is to set the height you want at design time, that's what designing is for. If you don't want to have a designable control, create it at run time. You may also set the height after the component has finished streaming, perhaps overriding Loaded or like, but that's pretty counter intuitive.

Comment: Autosize is True by default in Berlin;
 
 AutoSize - Enables the edit box to dynamically change its height depending on the currently selected font.

Comment: You may also want to review the docs for the difference in `Font.Height` and `Font.Size`. A font of size 9 will not fit into a edit of height 10.

Comment: You can override `Loaded` method of your component to force-adjust property values however you like after the root component (form) has been initialized from the dfm stream.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to change the Height property of the TEdit **you must first set the Autosize property to False**. otherwise, at runtime the control will change its height based on the font size.